# windows 8 Ensure that event logging is enabled

Tags: javascript, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

hi all i build an application using visual studio 2012 with javascript template for metro apps
i am trying to publish the app in store so that i test the application for windows certification kit it is testing the app and finally showing me the error like this saying in **performance test** .

```
     Bytecode generation

Error Found: The bytecode generation test detected the following errors:
    This package was deployed for development or authoring mode. Uninstall the package and re-install it normally.
Impact if not fixed: As a performance optimization to accelerate JavaScript execution time, JavaScript files ending in the ".js" extension generate bytecode when the app is deployed. This optimization significantly improves start-up and ongoing execution times for JavaScript.
How to fix: You may need consider one or more of these steps to fix the issue:
- Ensure that event logging is enabled
- All JavaScript files are syntactically valid; otherwise exclude the respective files from the package
- Please note that you should uninstall all previous versions of the app before deploying
Otherwise exclude the respective files from the package.
```

I resolve many errors but  finally it is not fixed saying failed, how to solve this can u know me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, go through all the .html, .css, and .js in visual studio and set their advanced save options to change the files to UTF8 w/ BOM.

With the file open, perform:

```
1) file
2) advanced save options...
3) select the UTF8 encoding
```

The save each file.